# Direct sum of indecomposable modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, direct-sum

**Prove or disprove:** There exist indecomposable modules $V,U,W$ such that $\displaystyle{ V \oplus U \cong V \oplus W }$ and $\displaystyle { U \not \cong W}$.

I think that this is true, but I have no idea how to construct such indecomposable modules.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Modules over what?  If we are looking at $R$-modules for $R$ a field, for example, then only one-dimensional spaces are indecomposable and there are no such examples.

Over $\mathbb{Z}$ there should be some interesting examples (hint: Hilbert's Hotel cannot be modeled directly, but there are some infinite groups that might behave similarly...).  In general, this is a hard and interesting problem without assumptions on $R$.  [This paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869304002959), for example, says some interesting things in the case where $R$ has dimension 1.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What assupmtions could we assume for $R$ to make it easier?

Comment: @passenger Good question.  If you want to cook up an $R$ for which such examples exist, it's probably possible to force certain simple modules to exist, and to ensure certain relations between them.  If this isn't homework, I might say more...

Comment: Νο it isn't...any details or some reference for this direction would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @passenger It's harder than I thought.  I don't have a lot of time to think about it, but it's rattling around my head and I'll let you if I solve it.  My only thought is that inverse limits/completions will provide a good source of indecomposable modules, e.g. $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as an abelian group.

Answer (score -2):

HINT: Take the quotient of both sides with respect to V.